# Не получается решить задачу

Tags: c++

Стоит задача:"

У каждого из нас есть повторяющиеся ежемесячные дела, каждое из которых нужно выполнять в конкретный день каждого месяца: оплата счетов за электричество, абонентская плата за связь и пр. Вам нужно реализовать работу со списком таких дел на месяц, а именно, реализовать набор следующих операций:

ADD i s
Назначить дело с названием s на день i текущего месяца.

DUMP i
Вывести все дела, запланированные на день i текущего месяца.

NEXT
Перейти к списку дел на новый месяц. При выполнении данной команды вместо текущего (старого) списка дел на текущий месяц создаётся и становится активным (новый) список дел на следующий месяц: все дела со старого списка дел копируются в новый список. После выполнения данной команды новый список дел и следующий месяц становятся текущими, а работа со старым списком дел прекращается. При переходе к новому месяцу необходимо обратить внимание на разное количество дней в месяцах:

если следующий месяц имеет больше дней, чем текущий, «дополнительные» дни необходимо оставить пустыми (не содержащими дел);
если следующий месяц имеет меньше дней, чем текущий, дела со всех «лишних» дней необходимо переместить на последний день следующего месяца.
Замечания
Историю списков дел хранить не требуется, работа ведется только с текущим списком дел текущего месяца. Более того, при создании списка дел на следующий месяц, он «перетирает» предыдущий список.
Обратите внимание, что количество команд NEXT в общей последовательности команд при работе со списком дел может превышать 11.
Начальным текущим месяцем считается январь.
Количества дней в месяцах соответствуют Григорианскому календарю с той лишь разницей, что в феврале всегда 28 дней.
Формат ввода
Сначала число операций Q, затем описания операций.

Названия дел s уникальны и состоят только из латинских букв, цифр и символов подчёркивания. Номера дней i являются целыми числами и нумеруются от 1 до размера текущего месяца.

Формат вывода
Для каждой операции типа DUMP в отдельной строке выведите количество дел в соответствующий день, а затем их названия, разделяя их пробелом. Порядок вывода дел в рамках каждой операции значения не имеет."

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


void ADD(vector <vector <string> >& vec, int num, string str ){
    vec[num].push_back(str);

}

void DUMP (vector <vector <string> >& vec, int num ){
    int i = vec[num].size();
    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        cout<<vec[num][j];
    }

}
void next_month( const vector <int> &m, int &num, vector <vector <string> >& vec){
    num ++;
    vector <vector <string> > vec_new(m[num]);
    vec_new.insert(end(vec_new), begin(vec), end(vec));
    vec = vec_new;
    vec_new.clear();
}







int main() {

    vector <int > month {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int current_month = 0;
    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    vector <vector <string> > vec(month[current_month]);
    for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++ ){
        string temp;

        cin >> temp;
        if(temp == "ADD"){
            int j;
            string str;
            cin>>j>>str;
            ADD(vec, j, str);

        }
        else if (temp == "DUMP"){
            int j;
            cin>>j;
            DUMP(vec, j);

        }
        else if (temp == "NEXT"){
                next_month(month, current_month,vec);

        }


    }


}
```

Функции "DUMP" и "ADD" работают,однако программа падает на выполнении функции "next".Сколько не пытался,никак не могу найти ошибку. Буду сильно благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
void next_month( const vector <int> &m, int &num, vector <vector <string> >& vec)    
{
    num = (num + 1) % 12;         // %12 is needed for december->january 

    if (vec.size() == m[num] )
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (vec.size() < m[num])
    {
        vec.resize(m[num]);
    }
    else
    {
         // copy all data from non-existing days to the last day of the month
         // ...
    }
}
```

Вам осталось дополнить код в последней части: `else ...`

Обратите внимание на следующие моменты:

1. Правильно оформлен переход на новый год.
2. Вектор преобразуется на месте, без дополнительного вектора.
3. Если новый месяц такой же длины, как предыдущий, вектор не изменяется.
4. Если новый месяц длиннее предыдущего, то к вектору добавляются пустые элементы.
5. Если новый месяц короче предыдущего, то надо скопировать все данные из лишних элементов в последний день, и изменить размер вектора. Эту часть я оставил вам для завершения задания.